# How to import caffe module in Python?

Tags: python, c++, dllimport, caffe

I have build .dll of _caffe.cpp on Windows (Release, x64).

I changed extension .dll to .pyd and trying to import it in python:

```
import caffe

  File "\caffe-master\python\caffe\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver

  File "\caffe-master\python\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

What does it mean, some module of dependencies missing which was included in project in Visual Studio, where I build this dll?

Comment: use [dependancy walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what is missing from your dll.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Python Caffe to PYTHONPATH. For example:
**export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/username/caffe/python**

Answer (score 2):

For windows :

Adding `/caffe/Build/x64/Release/pycaffe` to system path(`path`) works for me, and I think the best way to do it is :

1. New a system variable : `PYTHON_PKG = /caffe/Build/x64/Release/pycaffe;`
2. Include `PYTHON_PKG` in `path` : `path = %PYTHON_PKG%; %OtherDirs%`

After I did this, I get PKG missing `google.internal`, then I did `pip install google.internal` in `CMD`. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a compiled and built caffe, try

```
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/caff-dir/python'
```

Also, you may need to run following:

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```